# Connecting dynamically the 8 nearest lines to @map_extent_center in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, polyline-creation, geometry-generator, knn

Starting from a points geometry layer, I am working on the following function that has the goal of drawing 8 nearest lines to the `@map_extent_center` of the map view:

```
make_line(
    $geometry,
    @map_extent_center,
    overlay_nearest(@layer, $geometry, limit:=8)
    )
```

With the following result:

[image]

I've made another test that comes a bit closer to the goal but I can't manage to draw only the 5 nearest lines from point to `@map_center_extent`:

```
make_line($geometry, @map_extent_center)
```

[image]

The expected result would be something like this that redraws dynamically when panning or zooming in the map view:

[image]

The idea is to get a similar analysis effect developed by @AlasdairRae:

[http://alasdairrae.github.io/steakbakespider/](https://alasdairrae.github.io/steakbakespider/)

[image]

Comment: Just for curiosity: What is the use of this function? IMHO you described pretty well what you're trying to achieve, but it would be nice to have a bit of a "usecase background". EDIT: Saw your edit just now. Still not clear why one would need this.

Comment: I think it can have several applications and can be useful in KNN analysis projects. However, in my case and at the moment I am trying to reproduce Alasdair Rae's (Spidermap) application developed with turf.js with the capabilities of QGIS Geometry Generator.

Comment: But 5 legs? And that other map has 9 legs? 9, really? It's called *something something* ***spider***, give it 8 legs already!

Comment:  Edit Spider Title

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Create the lines from all points to the center of the map canvas with your expression, but aggregate them into an array with [`array_agg()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-agg).
2. Inside the array, order the lines according to their length, using the argument `order_by`.
3. Use [`array_slice()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-slice) to get only the first five (array index 0 to 4) elements.
4. As you use an aggregate function, all lines will be repeatedly created for all points you have. This is a huge waste of resources. So run the whole operation just once, e.g. for the feature with the smallest `$id` value using [`minimum()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#minimum) inside a [`case ... when`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#case) clause.

   **EDIT:** However, this has the disadvantage that the lines disappear if the point with the smallest `$id` value is outside the map canvas. For this reason, I changed the initial answer and replaced the `when` condition. It now runs the expression for the point that is closest to the canvas center.

You can do this with this expression:

```sql
case 
when 
    $geometry = 
    closest_point(
        collect($geometry),
        @map_extent_center
    )
then
    collect_geometries(
        array_slice( 
            array_agg( 
                make_line($geometry, @map_extent_center), 
                order_by:=length(make_line($geometry, @map_extent_center))
            ),
            0,
            4
        )
    )
end
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your description and documentation of how the solution works and what each function and parameter (array_agg, minimum, ordre_by, etc...) is used for